# No option to install Ubuntu from USB

Tags: installation

I've finally decided to delve into the world of LINUX, however I'm already experiencing problems before the installation.
I followed the instructions to put Ubuntu on a USB stick. It IS on there and it fires up when I open it but I only have 2 options: 'Demo and Full Installation' and 'Learn More' rather than then the 3 in the instructions.
When I click Demo and Full Installation it resets my computer but doesnt give me an option to install Ubuntu upon reboot.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you please provide more details like which Ubuntu you have put on USB stick using which utility, does your computer boot from USB when it reboots, and which options you have? Sometimes something might go wrong with the boot options but you can start demo version (try ubuntu) and click on the desktop icon for installing.

Comment: I downloaded ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386 right from the main page and put it on the USB using Universal-USB-Installer. When I reboot my computer it gives me no options, its logs me right into windows.

Comment: you need to check the boot settings in BIOS. Seems to me that the hard drive is before usb. Also you might be able to press a function key to get to a boot menu.

Comment: Have you made sure your USB stick is properly connected to your computer, and its boot order (from a boot menu or BIOS setup) is set to boot from your USB stick? If your answer to both questions is YES, then probably Universal USB Installer has not done a good job.

Comment: Success. I just needed to enter BIOS and from there it was straightforward.Thank you very much.